# How to use a variable with a string value as a name for another variable. Actually trying to set this in $.post (name : value) data parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Note `$thisname` and `$thisvalue`. I want `$thisname` to be the key/name and value assigned to it will be `$thisvalue`. As it currently is the name/value pair is invalid unless I replace $thisname with some static value which is not a variable.

```
function SaveNews($thisname, $thisvalue, $thispageid) {

    $.post('/Admin/SaveNews',

                { $thisname: $thisvalue, PageID: $thispageid },
                function (data) {

                });
            }
```

Comment: Use eval(), it's just like Google, not evil at all, and solves any problem you may have with variables, functions, and just about everything !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that with JavaScript object literal syntax. You can, however, construct the object you need.

```
var params = { PageID: $thispageid };
params[$thisname] = $thisvalue;
$.post('/Admin/SaveNews', params, function(data) { ... });
```